# How to add form django to jquery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

How to add form django to jQuery command? My table have a button inside row, when user click on button will insert new row. In column `Product` have a combobox load from database for user choose Product. But I have some problem with

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token class

Code:

```
<script>
    var rowIndex = 0;
    $("#addrow").on('click', function () {
        rowIndex++;

        var newRow = '<tr><td>'{{ item_info.item }}'</td>' +
                '<td><input id="Quantity' + rowIndex + '" name="Quantity' + rowIndex + '" type="text" /></td>"' +
                '<td><input id="Price' + rowIndex + '" name="Price' + rowIndex + '" type="text" /></td>"' +
                '<td><input id="Amount' + rowIndex + '" name="Amount' + rowIndex + '" type="text" /></td>"' +
                '<td><button type="button" class="removerow btn btn-white fa fa-minus" id="removerow' + rowIndex + '" name="removerow' + rowIndex + '" value="Remove">' +
                '</button></td></tr>';

        if ($("#dynamic-table > tbody > tr").is("*"))
            $("#dynamic-table > tbody > tr:last").after(newRow)
        else $("#dynamic-table > tbody").append(newRow)

    });

    $(document).on('click', "[class^=removerow]", function () {

        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
    });
</script>
```

When I view in browser, it displays errr

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token class.

And error in here:

```
var newRow = '<tr><td>' <select class="form-control" id="id_item" name="item"> --red error in here
  <option value="" selected="selected">---Select Item---</option>
  <option value="1">iPhone 5S</option>
  <option value="2">iPhone 6S</option>
  <option value="3">iPhone 4S</option>
  <option value="4">iPhone 4</option>
  <option value="5">Galaxy S7</option>
  <option value="6">Galaxy S7 Edge</option>
  <option value="7">Galaxy S6</option>
  </select> '</td>' +
                '<td><input id="Quantity' + rowIndex + '" name="Quantity' +            rowIndex + '" type="text" /></td>"' +
                '<td><input id="Price' + rowIndex + '" name="Price' + rowIndex + '" type="text" /></td>"' +
                '<td><input id="Amount' + rowIndex + '" name="Amount' + rowIndex + '" type="text" /></td>"' +
                '<td><button type="button" class="removerow btn btn-white fa fa-minus" id="removerow' + rowIndex + '" name="removerow' + rowIndex + '" value="Remove">' +
                '</button></td></tr>';
```

Comment: You should add the exact error you get (including linenumber, etc.). Otherwise it's difficult to help.

Comment: There is a syntax error in your python code somewhere. Check (and post here) the full stack trace to find out where.

Comment: When I view in browser, it display message Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token class. And Error in here:

Comment: I have already post error. Please help me. Thank you!

Comment: You've said what error but you should include the full traceback (as well as what you have researched so far to try to solve it yourself)

Comment: It don't have error in code back-end. It just displayed when I view in browser and check in source of browser